# Why does decreasing intake of protein prolongs the lifespan of a fly?

Tags: human-biology, zoology, lifespan

A book I read about aging suggests that it is established that a fly lives much longer when it is fed less protein. What does protein intake has to do with the lifespan of an organism? Why not carbohydrates?

Comment: In which book did you read this?

Comment: It is a Korean book of which author is a professor at New York University. I can search for the exact title, but I doubt it will help you.

Comment: Hmm. Do they have references to scientific articles in that? Korean would indeed not help me :-)